# SQL Server 2008: Collation for UTF-8 code page 65001

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, utf-8, collation

There is a need to save an XML in UTF-8 encoding and then use it in T-SQL code to extract data.

Default database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I don't know if it is possible to save and work with UTF-8 data in SQL Server 2008, but I have an idea to use collation with code page of UTF-8 (65001) on the XML column in order to save the data in UTF-8.

Does anybody know if it is possible or have another idea on how to work with UTF-8 data in SQL Server?

Comment: There is no necessity to store data in UTF-8. UTF-16 that is used for xml column is perfectly fine. When the data is provided to the outside through an additional layer (Java in my case) it may always be converted to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with xml data, store it as the xml data type.  That should take care of any concerns you have (i.e. how to store it) and you'll save yourself the work of having to convert it to xml when you do work on it (e.g. xpath expressions, xquery, etc).

Answer (score 0):

[NVARCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) column should do the job just fine.

Comment: What about returning results to the client in UCS-2 encoding instead of UTF-8?

Comment: If using NVARCHAR to store XML, your XML must contain UTF-16 BOM stuff or have `encoding="utf-16"` (and may not have any nonequivalent encoding specified). If you don’t do this, some problems you could encounter include SQL Server’s own built-in XML parsing stuff choking on the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all Unicode characters in `xml` or `nvarchar` columns. It does not matter what collation you use. A handful of rare Chinese characters (from the supplementary plane) may be stored as pairs of `nchars` (surrogate pairs). But there is no loss of data.